# Internet Explorer 11 designing issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

i am getting this
[image]

and i want output like

[image]

code here:

```
<div class="row col-sm-12 cms-img-fix cms-pdT25">

                <a class="cms-pdB50" href="https://www.radise.com/" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/images/base-images/RADISE_logo@2x.png">
                </a>
                <a class="cms-pdB50" href="https://www.testpile.com" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/images/base-images/AFT_0001_LOGO_HOR_WEB.png">
                </a>
                <a class="cms-pdB50" href="http://smart-structures.com/" target="_self">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/images/base-images/Group 16.png">
                </a>
                    </div>
```

i am getting designing issue in internet explorer 11 but in chrome designing it's perfect.

in Companies div i am getting problem in third image

please open below link

https://smart-structures-dev.azurewebsites.net/

in chrome and internet explorer 11 and then check **Companies** images  you observe difrences  in below image

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="/images/base-images/AFT_0001_LOGO_HOR_WEB.png">
```

can anyone help me for this problem

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output HERE, not in an external link which will likely not show the issue after you have fixed it. The image is 1600px by the way

Comment: The middle image is 1600px compared to 300 for the other two

Comment: @mplungjan  sorry for image size but the problem is different could you please open that link which  i had share ,open that link in chrome and in internet explorer  then you check that image which i had share

Comment: I did. That is likely the problem - the aspect ratio is different in IE on that size

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for information but could you suggest me any solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check your site with IE 11 browser. I check the source code and CSS.

I found that you are using flex. [CSS flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) has some issues with IE browser. It is not able to calculate the height and width properly in many scenarios.

I noticed that in your CSS code you are using **max-height** and **max-width** for that 2 images.

[image]

[image]

If you replace the **max-width** with **width** and replace the **max-height** with **height** the issue can be solved.

```
width: 100%;
height:100%;
```

Result in IE 11 after making above changes:

[image]